# Flickering all tiles when i click a tile

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have the following component.
Everything works really well except that when I want click on a tile, all the tiles flicker.
If I comment out the setState() then the color change does not occur.
I havent seen other people have the same issue on stackoverflow.

If there is other ways of doing this, such as using a third package let me know.

Is it even possible to accomplish a change like that?

Any help is welcomed

```
class CompanyUserListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String companyId;
  CompanyUserListWidget({super.key, required this.companyId});

  @override
  State<CompanyUserListWidget> createState() => _CompanyUserListWidgetState();
}

class _CompanyUserListWidgetState extends State<CompanyUserListWidget> {
  late bool _isLoading = false;
  final CompanyUserFirebaseCloudStorage _companyInviteReposatory =
      CompanyUserFirebaseCloudStorage();
  final UserFirebaseCloudStorage _userReposatory = UserFirebaseCloudStorage();
  late String _companyId;
  List<int> _selectedUsersIndexes =
      []; // Track the selection state for each tile

  @override
  void initState() {
    _companyId = widget.companyId;
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test')),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: StreamBuilder<List<CloudCompanyUser>>(
              stream:
                  _companyInviteReposatory.getCompanyUsersStream(_companyId),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<CloudCompanyUser>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot.error);
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final companyUser = snapshot.data![index];
                    return _buildUserCompanyTile(companyUser, index);
                  },
                );
              },
            )),
          ],
        ));
  }

  _buildUserCompanyTile(companyUser, int index) {
    bool isSelected = _selectedUsersIndexes
        .contains(index); // Track the selection state of the tile

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: findUserById(companyUser.user_id),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Error fetching data');
          }
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data.name),
            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.email),
            trailing: isSelected
                ? Icon(Icons.check)
                : null, // Add the check mark icon

            onTap: () {
              if (isSelected) {
                _selectedUsersIndexes.remove(index);
              } else {
                _selectedUsersIndexes.add(index);
              }
              setState(() {});
            },
            tileColor: isSelected
                ? Colors.green
                : null, // Change the color based on selection state
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // Future<String?>
  Future<CloudUser?> findUserById(userId) async {
    return await _userReposatory.findUserById(userId);
  }

  onNewCompany() {
    // Navigator.push(
    //   context,
    //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CompaniesEdit()),
    // );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this behaviour is that the FutureBuilder widget inside **_buildUserCompanyTile** is causing a rebuild of the list tiles when the state is updated.

The solution is, you can modify your code to separate the tile widget into a separate **StatefulWidget** and use **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** to maintain the state of each tile when the list rebuilds.

Updated Exampled:

```
class _CompanyUserListWidgetState extends State<CompanyUserListWidget> {
  late bool _isLoading = false;
  final CompanyUserFirebaseCloudStorage _companyInviteReposatory =
      CompanyUserFirebaseCloudStorage();
  final UserFirebaseCloudStorage _userReposatory = UserFirebaseCloudStorage();
  late String _companyId;
  List<int> _selectedUsersIndexes = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _companyId = widget.companyId;
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<List<CloudCompanyUser>>(
              stream: _companyInviteReposatory.getCompanyUsersStream(_companyId),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<CloudCompanyUser>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot.error);
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final companyUser = snapshot.data![index];
                    return CompanyUserTile(
                      companyUser: companyUser,
                      isSelected: _selectedUsersIndexes.contains(index),
                      onSelect: () => _toggleUserSelection(index),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _toggleUserSelection(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (_selectedUsersIndexes.contains(index)) {
        _selectedUsersIndexes.remove(index);
      } else {
        _selectedUsersIndexes.add(index);
      }
    });
  }
}

class CompanyUserTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final CloudCompanyUser companyUser;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Function() onSelect;

  const CompanyUserTile({
    required this.companyUser,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.onSelect,
  });

  @override
  _CompanyUserTileState createState() => _CompanyUserTileState();
}

class _CompanyUserTileState extends State<CompanyUserTile> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // Ensure that the state is kept alive

    return FutureBuilder<CloudUser?>(
      future: findUserById(widget.companyUser.user_id),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<CloudUser?> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Error fetching data');
          }
          final user = snapshot.data;
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(user?.name ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(user?.email ?? ''),
            trailing: widget.isSelected ? Icon(Icons.check) : null,
            onTap: widget.onSelect,
            tileColor: widget.isSelected ? Colors.green : null,
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<CloudUser?> findUserById(String userId) async {
    return await _userReposatory.findUserById(userId);
  }
}
```